# Nativescript how to start a service?

Tags: nativescript

I am trying to start a basic service ( base on this example https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-geolocation/blob/master/demo/app/main-page.ts) for android (sdk 24) but nothing happening and not sure what i am doing wrong, here is my code :

```
function onNavigatingTo(args) {
     
        const page    = args.object;
        const context = utils.ad.getApplicationContext();
        if(platformModule.device.sdkVersion < '26'){
            android.app.IntentService.extend("com.tns.notifications.BackgroundService", {
                onHandleIntent(intent) {
                    console.log('service onHandleIntent');
                },
                onStartCommand(){
                    console.log('service onStartCommand');
                }
            });
    
            let intent = new android.content.Intent(context, com.tns.notifications.BackgroundService.class);
            intent.setFlags(android.content.Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startService(intent);
    
    
        }
        page.bindingContext = createViewModel();
    
}
```

in **mainfest.xml** i added the "service" tag:

```
<service android:name="com.nativescript.location.BackgroundService"
                 android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"
                 android:enabled="true"
                 android:exported="false" >
```

The `"onHandleIntent"` or `"onStartCommand"` never fired after the app starts, Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

The code I posted to this Nativescript-geolocation [issue](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-geolocation/issues/256) might be pertinent.

Comment: Thank you David, i found the problem, i entered wrong service name in the mainfest.xml "service" tag. Instead of "com.tns.notifications.BackgroundService" i entered "com.nativescript.location.BackgroundService", once i fixed it, the service started to work. Silly mistake :(